# Top bar of Application does not show, when using external Monitor Ubuntu Budgie Desktop

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments, budgie

When I connect to my laptop external Monitor, and every application that I open in full window size (on the laptop screen) it does not have the top bar (minimize,maximize, close).

I was using Gnome and after I installed Ubuntu-Budgie Desktop this is happening, and also some keyboard shortcuts don't work.

How can i fix this ?

[image]

Thank you.